# Removing ZooKeeper node in Kafka cluster procedure?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

What is the best way, procedure to remove Zookeeper node from Kafka cluster because of infrastructure changes?

Is it enought to stop this one node, remove it from Kafka configuration and do rolling restart all Kafka nodes?

Comment: As long as you don't end up with 2 remaining Zookeepers, this seems fine. You might want to take backups of stuff, anyway

Comment: I want to remove one zookeeper node and next add new one. That's why I am looking for such a procedure.

Comment: Yes, I understood your question, and I said that should be fine. I'd recommend adding a new one before removing one, though.